# Get ID of entity after creating

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have 2 entities that are joined by foreign key so when I crete second entity I must specify parent entities ID.

The parent entities ID is generated automatically when I create it so how do I grab that ID to specifiy when creating the child?

```
db.ParentClasses.Add(new ParentClass
    { 
        name = "test"

    });
db.ChildClasses.Add(new ChildClass
    {
        name = "test",
        someValue = "thing";
        parentID = ?????? // I have just created the parent above, how do I get the ID?
    });
db.SaveChanges();
```

I tried running that without specifying the parent entity ID and no error is thrown but only the parent entity is created.  The child entity is not created and no error is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `parentID` in the child class, you utilize the parent class object itself. Here is quick pseudo code.

```
var parent = new ParentClass() { name = "parent"};
var child = new ChildClass() { name = "child", parent = parent };
db.ParentClasses.Add(parent);
db.ChildClasses.Add(child);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and child is created and ID's are correct on parent record but child record doesnt have ID of parent but I think that is due to my annotations so I will check into that.